# "do my costumes rule?" meaning

Tags: idiomatic-language, figurative-language, culture

Could you check the following dialogue from the sitcom 'How I Met Your Mother' (season 1, episode 6 *Slutty Pumpkin*)?

> Guess what came in the mail today?
>
> Our costumes? Do they rule?
>
> Yeah, they rule. And yours is 100% wool.

I didnt understand the part "*do they rule?*". I switched language back to my native and it says "are they perfect?"
What does "*do they rule*?" mean in this case?

Comment: This dialogue is nonsense.  Do you mean "costumes"? Who is speaking?  Are the teens from the 1980s?

Comment: Your questions often include a quote or a fragment which you ask us to "check".  This is not a good style of question.  You *must* include the source of the quote, (eg as a link or URL)

Comment: Ohh I just noticed that I wrote "customes" I meant "costumes" sorry for little ortographic error, my brain sometimes tricks me. Anyway, yes the movie I watched is a sitcom from the 90s. Im newbie here and I will follow what you said sir. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I've done some formatting,  you can fill in the name of the sitcom (and the episode number) in the gap ..........

Comment: I've heard exclamatory ***X rules**!* *(X is excellent!)* countless times, but I've *never* heard anyone ask ***Does X rule**?* with the meaning ***Is X any good**?* By the same token, I doubt anyone would ever say ***X doesn't rule*** with the intended meaning ***X is no good***. I'm tempted to assume either the scriptwriter here is mistakenly trying to extend a colloquial usage beyond its normal remit, OR it's deliberately quirky phrasing for the sake of (comedic?) effect. Either way, I'd certainly advise learners not to copy it.

Answer (score 3):

To say something "rules" is an informal or slang way of saying that it's the best.

For instance:

> San Dimas high school football rules!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, to say something "rules" is a slang way of saying it's great. It's not at all normal to ask "Does something rule?". Having watched that TV series through twice, I can confidently say it's deliberately quirky phrasing to show they are very close friends who have developed their own internal slang and odd phrasing.

In short, that line is not worth learning English from.